# Azure Devops pipeline error in .net test .net core 2.2.0 framework project

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I am using the Azure Devops pipeline.
From 2020/6/25, an error has occurred.

task:dotnet test
Error: The framework'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.

What I care about:
When it was successful, the following display.

```
Welcome to .NET Core 3.1!
---------------------
SDK Version: 3.1.300
```

Tasks when it starts to fail:

```
Welcome to .NET Core 3.1!
---------------------
SDK Version: 3.1.301
```

The dotnet test portion of the Yml file is as follows
version was used before the error. Added minorVersion and patchVersion, but they did not work.
I added the x86 version of arguments, but it didn't work either.

```
pool:
vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
solution: '**/TamaWeb.sln'
buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
buildConfiguration: 'Release'
#  disable.coverage.autogenerate: 'true'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
inputs:
 versionSpec: '>=5' 
 checkLatest: true
 
- task: NuGetCommand@2
inputs:
 restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
 
- task: VSBuild@1
inputs:
 solution: '$(solution)'
 msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
 platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
 configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

 task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: dotnet test
   inputs:
     command: test
     # test core version
     # version: '2.2'
     majorVersion: '3' 
     minorVersion: '1' 
     patchVersion: '300' 
     arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura --runtime win-x86'
     projects: '**/*[Tt]est/*[Tt]est.csproj'
  #   projects: '**/*Test/TamaCoreTest.csproj'
     nobuild: true
```

csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.8.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\XXX\AAA.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\XXX\BBB.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\XXX\CCC.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.test.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><UserProperties appsettings_1test_1json__JsonSchema="" /></VisualStudio></ProjectExtensions>

</Project>
```

Is it possible to specify the above SDK version with the dotnet test task?
If you know another solution, please help.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline's YAML file?

Comment: Austin S、返信ありがとう。
Ymlファイルのdotnet test部分を記載しました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Can you also include your test project .csproj file(s)?

Comment: The test project csproj file has been posted.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: 2.2 is end of life. Switch to 2.1 or 3.1. And then install the required runtime if not yet installed, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script#examples

Comment: Thank you, Lex Li.
I'm convinced.
Upgrade the .net core.
Thank you all so much!

Comment: @fukufuku Is your issue solved after upgrading the .net core?

Comment: I'm in the process of bringing it down to 2.1. I'm sorry, I just need a little more time.

Comment: @fukufuku Kindly let us know your test once it is done.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT

Thank you Cece Dong - MSFT

2.1 is not supported by the OSS and cannot be lowered. I'm trying to raise it to 3.1 now, but it's taking a long time.
Please wait for a while.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: The framework'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.

Your test project TargetFramework is 2.2.0, yet specified in your testing task as 3.1.300

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

```
 task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: dotnet test
   inputs:
     command: test
     # test core version
     # version: '2.2'
     majorVersion: '3'   <---
     minorVersion: '1'   <---
     patchVersion: '300' <---
```

You will want to make sure your project's .Net Core version is the same in:

- Your project's .csproj file(s)
- Any tasks specifying a runtime or version
- Your App Service (managed in your [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/))

Comment: Austin S, thanks for the reply.

> It appears your test project was made in 2.2.0, yet specified in Azure as 3.1.

That's right, I'm concerned about the above.
But it's been working fine until now.
If it's as you pointed out, you can go to "variables" or "NuGetToolInstaller" I also think that the parameters of
I wonder if there is anything wrong with the parameters.

I've also added the top of the Yml file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 2.2 is end of life.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2/runtime/?utm_source=getdotnetcore&utm_medium=referral

I faced the same problem as well, found a workaround for it, before the test task add the below task,

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2

  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.2.100'

inputs:
version: 2.2.100

It basically adds 2.2 version on the fly. You can either use sdk / runtime.
Make sure the version is same as in your project.

Comment: Thank you.Virendra M Patil

I just tried it earlier, but the situation is the same.
Maybe it's a bad position to set a task.

Is it OK to set the task just before "DotNetCoreCLI@2"?

thanks

Comment: Yeah, thats why its just a work around this until its converted to .net core 2.1 or .net core 3.x, as long as its added before the test task it should work well.